# permission() for permission in self.permission_classes -> TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

does anybody know why do I get this error? I set default permission to IsAuthenticated. Only register has AllowAny, to allow users to register.

```
Not Found: /
[21/Feb/2022 21:43:06] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 2278
Not Found: /account
[21/Feb/2022 21:43:11] "GET /account HTTP/1.1" 404 2317
Internal Server Error: /account/register
Traceback (most recent call last):
\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 278, in <listcomp>
    return [permission() for permission in self.permission_classes]
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
[21/Feb/2022 21:43:14] "GET /account/register HTTP/1.1" 500 106055
```

My `views.py` class:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes(['AllowAny'])
def registration_view(request):
    serializer = RegistrationSerializer(data=request.data)
    data = {}
    if serializer.is_valid():
        account = serializer.save()
        data['response'] = "successfully registered a new user."
        data['email'] = account.email
        data['username'] = account.username
    else:
        data = serializer.errors
    return Response(data)
```

I am using SessionAuthentication and IsAuthenticated as default authentication and permission in my settings.py file.

`CustomUser` model just inherits from `AbstractUser`. No addition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not pass the permission classes as strings, but as references to classes, so:

```
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny

@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes([AllowAny])
def registration_view(request):
    # …
```

but you do not need to specify `AllowAny` since, well, it allows any request. You can implement the view with:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def registration_view(request):
    # …
```

Comment: But I specified IsAuthenticated as default permission. Still don't need AllowAny?

Comment: @Freddy: in that case yes, but that was of course not clear form the context :)